# Neo4J search word not knowing what is the size of the letters

Tags: search, neo4j, letters

how to search node without knowing what size are letters small or big

```
match (w:item) WHERE w.value='Book' return w;
```

Answer (score 1):

Case-insensitive search? The idea is that you convert both sides of the comparison to the same case.

That would be:

```
MATCH (w:item)
WHERE lower(w.value) = 'book'
RETURN w;
```

The [lower()](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-string.html#functions-lower) function returns a string in lower case.